# ckeditor and inline editor both are in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor, config

i have  a main page with **ckeditor** and i need another control as a **inline ckeditor**(in same page).

I have added some code for click event on CKEDITOR(not inline). And this click event also coming in Inline editor also, how can i avoid that event not triggered on Inline editor.
.how can i configure that.

**inline editor :**

```
    CKEDITOR.inline(document.getElementById(Element),{
removePlugins: 'maximize,resize',
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,

                        toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']]
                    });
```

Comment: Could you try to rewrite your question with more details what should (not) happen and what do you have? I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create multiple instances on the same page, and pass in separate options?

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { height: 100 });

CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', {
    removePlugins: 'maximize,resize',
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']]
});
```